# How to create composite index which contains the (latitude,longitude) and other datatype column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    longid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_longid_seq'::regclass),
    longitude double precision,
    latitude double precision,
    create_ts_long bigint,
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (longid)
)
```

We can use this to create the gist index :

```
CREATE INDEX ll_idx
    ON test USING gist
    (ll_to_earth(latitude ::double precision, longitude ::double precision))
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

But there is a scenario that I want to find the nearest records of the specific time(create_ts_long).

So how to create such composite index? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Install the `btree_gist` contrib module.
Then you have a `gist_int8_ops` operator class that you can use to create a GiST index on a `bigint` column.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to create a composite gist index?

Comment: Like any other index: `CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gist (col1, col2)`.